# second parameter content_tag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dropdown in the form i'm using

```
<%= f.select(:visitable_id) do %>
      <% @visitors.each do |visitor| %>
        <%= content_tag(:option, visitor.name, value: visitor.id, data: {:type => visitor.class.name.to_s} ) %>
      <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

When submitted I get the visitable_id in the controller. But I would also like to receive the data of the data value in the content_tag. The: data: {:type => visitor.class.name.to_s}

How can you access the second value in the controller? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 data attributes are not sent with the form. Nor is anything else except the name and value of the inputs.

You could solve it by passing both values through a single option.

```
<%= f.select(:visitable_id) do %>
  <% @visitors.each do |visitor| %>
    <%= content_tag(:option, visitor.name, value: "#{visitor.class.name}=visitor.id") %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can then parse them out by splitting the string:

```
klass, id = params[:visitable_id].split('=')
```

But make sure you whitelist the acceptable values for `klass` to avoid a vulnerability where a malicious user can query any model.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!